# How would I loop this Function over column Q with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and it does what I want it to as far as removing the data I want to remove. The only thing is I have to run it over and over and over for it to get through all of the data. How would I get this to loop over just column q?

```vb
Sub SdeleteDeclinesfoReal()
    Dim sString As String
    Dim MyAr
    Dim i As Long
    Dim delRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Add more to the list here separated by "/"
    sString = "Declined/Self ACH"

    MyAr = Split(sString, "/")
    With ws
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            Set aCell = .Columns(17).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
              LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase :=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(aCell.Row)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(aCell.Row))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
    End With
'...
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add a loop that, once the find is executed and has returned a find, executes `FindNext` until not no hits are found.

Comment: Eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426963/445425)

Answer (score 1):

### Loop Through Column

**A Find Method Solution**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SdeleteDeclinesfoReal()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const CritCol As String = "Q"
    Dim Criteria As Variant
    '~~> Add more to the list here
    Criteria = Array("Declined", "Self ACH")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, delRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sString As String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Define range "Q2:Q1048576" (FirstRow, CritCol).
    Set rng = ws.Cells(FirstRow, CritCol).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1)
    ' Define last non-blank cell.
    Set rng = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ' Define 'non-blank' range.
        Set rng = ws.Cells(FirstRow, CritCol).Resize(rng.Row - FirstRow + 1)
        With rng
            For i = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)
                sString = Criteria(i)
                Set aCell = .Find(What:=sString, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = aCell.Address
                    Do
                        If delRange Is Nothing Then
                            Set delRange = aCell.EntireRow
                        Else
                            Set delRange = Union(delRange, aCell.EntireRow)
                        End If
                        Set aCell = .FindNext(aCell)
                    ' Prevent infinite loop caused by the 'FindNext' method.
                    Loop Until aCell.Address = FirstAddress
                Else
                    ' Criteria not found.
                End If
                ' Prevent infinite loop when a criteria is found and one
                ' of the next is not.
                Set aCell = Nothing
            Next i
        End With
        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then
            delRange.Select ' Test with 'Select'. Later change to 'Delete'.
        Else
          ' Nothing cell found.
        End If
    Else
      ' All cells below first row are blank (empty or "").
    End If

End Sub
```

**A Reminder Why to Use Union**

- Copy the examples into a standard module, e.g. `Module1` of a new workbook.
- The first two procedures show how to increase efficiency using an array, but are primarily here to better understand what the last three procedures do.
- Run the trio each after populating the values, and monitor how long they take and look at the `ActiveSheet` before and after to see the differences.

**Test Union**

```
Option Explicit

' Slow
Sub populateValuesSlow()
    Const NoR As Long = 5000
    Const NoC As Long = 10
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To NoR
        For j = 1 To NoC
            Cells(i, j) = Int(Rnd() * (10 - 1)) + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

' Fast
Sub populateValuesFast()
    Const NoR As Long = 5000
    Const NoC As Long = 10
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To NoR, 1 To NoC)
    For i = 1 To NoR
        For j = 1 To NoC
            Data(i, j) = Int(Rnd() * (10 - 1)) + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
End Sub

' Wrong: in this case, half of the data still remains.
Sub deleteRowsOneRowAtTheTimeWrong()
    Const NoR As Long = 5000
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To NoR
        Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub

' Right but Slow
Sub deleteRowsOneRowAtTheTime()
    Const NoR As Long = 5000
    Dim i As Long
    For i = NoR To 1 Step -1
        Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub

' Right and Fast
Sub deleteRowsWithUnion()
    Const NoR As Long = 5000
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To NoR
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = Union(rng, Rows(i))
        Else
            Set rng = Rows(i)
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well let me describe your scenary:
You have a list in this case your list is

*sString = "Declined/Self ACH"* (for this example your list have 2 elements)

then you have a table that have at least 17 columns ( *Set aCell = .Columns(17).Find*) and with your program you search all rows that have in column 17 a value that is in your list then put all that "rows" in a range (delRange) and delete all rows in that range

In this point your code only find firts match for each element in your list so you Range (delRange) have  maximum size equal maximum size your list (for this example 2).
OK for me:
Why you save a range with elements that you are going to delete?
you can insert a delete instruction in second loop that others user suggest you, but instead use `.Findnext` you use another `.find`

```
PO=17  /*PO is whatever column you want*/
For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            Set aCell = .Columns(PO).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
           Do
           .Rows(aCell.Row).Delete
           Set aCell = .Columns(PO).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
           Loop While Not aCell Is Nothing
        End If
    Next i
```